# What is the weby-icon-cache folder in my home folder?

Tags: launchy

The title pretty much says it all.

Can I delete it?

What are these .ico files for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launchy stores its icon cache there.
If you're using it - leave it be, if not - delete.